# Scraping hierarchical data

Tags: xml, r, xpath, xml-parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the list of Dept stores for continent/countries from [global Dept stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_department_stores_by_country). I am running the following code to get the continents first, as we can see the XML hierarchy is in such a way that the countries withing each continent are not child nodes of that continent.

```
> url<-"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_department_stores_by_country"
> doc = htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)
> nodeNames = getNodeSet(doc, "//h2/span[@class='mw-headline']")
> # For Africa
> xmlChildren(nodeNames[[1]])
$a
<a href="/wiki/Africa" title="Africa">Africa</a> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLInternalNodeList" "XMLNodeList"        
> xmlSize(nodeNames[[1]])
[1] 1
```

I know I could do the countries in a seperate getNodeSet command but I just wanted to make sure I am not missing something. Is there a smarter way to get all the data within each continent and then within each country all at once?

Comment: Given the structure of your document, it may be easier to parse it with SAX rather than use the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uisng xpath, Several paths can be combined with | separator. So I use it to get contries and shops in the same list. Then I get a second list of contries.  I use the latter list to split the first one

```
url<-"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_department_stores_by_country"
library(XML)
xmltext <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes = T)

## Here I use the combined xpath 
cont.shops <- xpathApply(xmltext, '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul/li|
                                   //*[@id="mw-content-text"]/h3',xmlValue)
cont.shops<- do.call(rbind,cont.shops)                  ## from list to  vector


head(cont.shops)                  ## first element is country followed by shops
     [,1]                   
[1,] "[edit] Â Tunisia"     
[2,] "Magasin GÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©ral"
[3,] "Mercure Market"       
[4,] "Promogro"             
[5,] "Geant"                
[6,] "Carrefour"            
## I get all the contries in one list 
contries <- xpathApply(xmltext, '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/h3',xmlValue)
contries <- do.call(rbind,contries)                     ## from list to  vector

    head(contries)
     [,1]                   
[1,] "[edit] Â Tunisia"     
[2,] "[edit] Â Morocco"     
[3,] "[edit] Â Ghana"       
[4,] "[edit] Â Kenya"       
[5,] "[edit] Â Nigeria"     
[6,] "[edit] Â South Africa"
```

Now I do some processing to split the cont.shops using countries.

```
dd <- which(cont.shops %in% contries)                   ## get the index of contries
freq <- c(diff(dd),length(cont.shops)-tail(dd,1)+1)     ## use diff to get Frequencies
contries.f <- rep(contries,freq)                        ## create the factor splitter


ll <- split(cont.shops,contries.f)
```

I can check the result:

```
> ll[[contries[1]]]
[1] "[edit] Â Tunisia"      "Magasin GÃƒÂ©nÃƒÂ©ral" "Mercure Market"        "Promogro"              "Geant"                
[6] "Carrefour"             "Monoprix"             
> ll[[contries[2]]]
[1] "[edit] Â Morocco"                                                         
[2] "Alpha 55, one 6-story store in Casablanca"                                
[3] "Galeries Lafayette, to open in 2011[1] within Morocco Mall, in Casablanca"
```